# automated job to import data from one server to live server and cutting the live data before copy

Tags: sql-server, ssis, cloud

I am creating a SSIS Pacakage to import data from pre-prod to live weekly basis via automated job. Below is requirement.

Pre-prod/ [dbo].[tblGCImport]

Only the following columns I am copying:

[SOURCE_ID]
[GREEN_SCORE]

and They need to be copied to:

Live/ [dbo].[tblInsolvencyAnalyticsCategory]

And mapped to live columns

[clmRef]  -([Source_ID] in pre-prod)
[clmCat]  - ([GREEN_SCORE] in pre-prod)

The data should be deleted from the Live table before copying.

and  package to be deployed as a job to run Sun evening weekly.

I am not sure how to cut live data automatically before copying.

Please if you can advise how to cut live data and create automated job?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you need to truncate the live database table data, use execute sql task before Dataflow task to truncate the data from the table.

Comment: Thanks really grateful. Please if you can refer me some links related to it or number of starting from creating package, cutting live data and running job that will be useful.

Comment: [link](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/12/ssis-videos.html) here you can find great articles related to SSIS

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I figured  it for particular table-/** First clear out the destination table fast and easy without log bloat**/
TRUNCATE TABLE [DestinationDB].[dbo].[DestinationTable];

/**-- Now just insert everything into it **/
INSERT INTO [DestinationDB].[dbo].[DestinationTable]
SELECT * FROM [SourceDB].[dbo].[SourceTable];   Now I need to map particular column